# How to show that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{1+i} )$ is not contained in any cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to show that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{1+i} )$ is normal and thus nonabelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, but got stuck.

The main problem is that for the extension to be normal $\root4\of{1-i}$ should also be an element. I failed to show that.

Thank you for your helps.

----------------------edit---------------

My question arose from [this document](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf), page 5, Remark 2.7. It is given as a counterexample of Kronecker and Weber theorem:

When $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$, $K(\root4\of{1-i})$ can never be any intermediate field of $K({ \zeta  }_{ n })/K$, where ${ \zeta  }_{ n }$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

I first expected that above statement could be proved by showing that $K(\root4\of{1-i})$ is not abelian over  $\mathbb{Q}$ since any cyclotomic extension of K is a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ thus abelian.
However from your advices, it seems that it's not even normal. But I can't still understand the method you showed me..

Is there any more easy explanation for this?

When $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$, $K(\root4\of{1-i})$ can never be any intermediate field of $K({ \zeta  }_{ n })/K$, where ${ \zeta  }_{ n }$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

I only know about elementary field and Galois theory.

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: I tried to show that whether $\sqrt[4]{1-i}$ is in the field or not, but failed.

Comment: In the future add a description of your attempt to the question body, please. It may feel unnecessary for the purposes of describing the problem, but over the years our homework policy has evolved in such a way that this is a good way to prevent negative attention. Check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for alternative ways of adding (useful) meat on top of the skeleton question.

Comment: Missus is calling me for my morning oats, so I cannot think about this very hard, but my first reaction is that something is not right. This is a degree eight extension. For it to also contain $\root4\of{1-i}$ it would have to contain the ratio of the conjugate fourth roots. And that ratio is a root of unity of order sixteen. But, the sixteenth cyclotomic field is abelian of degree eight, and would have to be equal to the splitting field.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(i, (1+i)^{1/4})=\Bbb{Q}( (1+i)^{1/4})$, it is of course non-normal over $\Bbb{Q}$. It is normal and cyclic of degree $4$ over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$. The normal closure of $\Bbb{Q}( (1+i)^{1/4})$ is the splitting field of $x^{16}+4$ which is $L=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{16},(-4)^{1/16})$ which is of degree $32$.

Comment: Right @reuns, I realized nonnormality as I was pulling the covers over my head last night. Of course $x^{16}+4=(x^8+2x^4+2)(x^8-2x^4+2)$. Are you sure one needs to go to a degree-$32$ extension for normality? Without sitting down with pen and paper, I would have thought $16$ would do well enough.

Comment: @Lubin My reasoning was that $(1+i)^{1/4}/(1-i)^{1/4}=(2i)^{1/4}/2^{1/4}$ so $\zeta_{16}$ is in the splitting field and hence $x^{16}+4$ splits completely, so  our field is its splitting field. I asked magma to find that it is of degree $32$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce the extensions $k=\mathbf Q(i)=\mathbf Q(1+i), K=k(\sqrt {1+i})=\mathbf Q(i,\sqrt {1+i}), L=\mathbf Q(i,\sqrt [4] {1+i})$. By construction, the extension $K/k$ is quadratic, and from the definition of normality,  $K/\mathbf Q$ is normal iff $K$ is stabilized by all the prolongations of the generator $\gamma$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(k/\mathbf Q)$ ("complex conjugation") to embeddings of $K$ into $\bar {\mathbf Q}$. Obviously, this happens iff $\gamma ({1+i})/(1+i)\in {k^*}^{2}$. But the quotient is equal to $i$, so $K/\mathbf Q$ is *not* normal.

Let us look now at $L/\mathbf Q$. Since $k=\mathbf Q(1+i)$  contains the $4$-th roots of unity, Kummer theory tells us that $L/k$ is cyclic of degree $4$. It follows that the Kummer dual $R=\left<1+i\right>\bmod {k^*}^4\subset {k^*/k^*}^4$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)$ is also cyclic of order $4$, and $L/\mathbf Q$ is normal iff $\gamma (R)=R$, which means that $ (1-i)/(1+i)^h\in {k^*}^{4}$, for a certain $h$ which is invertible mod $4$, i.e. $h \equiv \pm 1$ mod $4$. All calculations done, I find that this cannot happen. So there must be an error, either in my calculations or in the question.

Comment: Hi there, does this show $L$ is not in any cyclotomic extension of $k$?