# Let $K=\mathbb Q[i]$. Show that $K(\sqrt[4]{1+i})$ does not lie in any cyclotomic extension of $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Note this question was previously discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506387/how-to-show-that-mathbbqi-sqrt41i-is-not-contained-in-any-cyclotom), but I think the question is not fully answered. The problem comes from  Remark 2.7 of [this paper](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf) by Keith Conrad.

Let $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{1+i}$. I think $K(\alpha)$ is actually the splitting field of $x^4-(1+i)=(x-\alpha)(x+\alpha)(x-\alpha i)(x+\alpha i)$ over $K$. Hence $K(\alpha)$ is a Galois extension over $K$ (as it is the splitting field of a separable polynomial) and the Galois group is abelian since it is a group of 4 elements. In fact, $\text{Gal}(K(\alpha)/K)\cong\mathbb Z_4$; try the $K$-automorphism induced by $\theta(\alpha)=\alpha i$, which has order 4. Therefore $K(\alpha)$ is an abelian extension.

But how do we show that $K(\alpha)$ does not lie in any cyclotomic extension of $K$?

Comment: The linked question has an accepted answer. Which part of that answer do you think is not right?

Comment: @user26857 I did not see a direct answer to the question "$K(\alpha)$ does not lie in any cyclotomic extension of $K$". In the answer of that link, it seems nguyen quang do showed that $K(\alpha)$ is not normal over $\mathbb Q$, does this answer the question I am asking?

Comment: @YuqiaoHuang: yes, it does. Every cyclotomic extension is abelian, so every subgroup of the Galois group is normal. By the Galois correspondence, this means that every subfield is normal, since every subfield is the fixed field of a normal subgroup.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I think it's better to post your comment as an answer in order to remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thank you! Yes I recall that every cyclotomic extension is abelian, so shouldn't we show $K(\alpha)$ is not normal over $K$ instead of over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: $K$ itself is cyclotomic over $\Bbb Q$, so any cyclotomic over $K$ must also be cyclotomic over $\Bbb Q$.